# Gathering all .class files in one place using .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory which has 112 folders, each of which has X sub-folders(X may vary with each parent folder) containing .class files. I have to do some analysis on those class files for which I first need all files in one folder. How do I make a batch script for this?

I made a batch file which lists all .class files in given folder.

```js
FOR %%c in (A:\src\testcases\CWE90\CWE90_LDAP_Injection\*.*) DO move %%c A:\Input\
pause
```

Comment: In a console window, type `help for`.  Specifically, `for /r` is what you need.  Alternatively, you could use `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a:-d "a:\src\*.class"')` if you need to include hidden files or folders.

Comment: Using this command I am getting the file name but not the whole path, since I want to move the files using move command, I would need the path as well, ins't it?

Comment: `for /f`... etc. `DO move "%%~fI" A:\Input`.  The `~f` strips surrounding quotation marks if applicable and expands to a fully qualified path + filename.  Again, I strongly encourage you to do `help for` in a console window.

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified. This is the error I get

Comment: Its working now. I had made one silly typing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the following code in a collectclass.bat file

`for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b *.class') do move %%~fI A:\Input
pause`

It collects all class files and places it in directory A:\Input